# How to find un-well-answered questions, of which I see a pattern?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

The pattern goes : **high question score, low top answer score**. SE doesn't list it as unanswered. The asker often understands to some extent that no good answer is or will ever be provided, yet ***the community wants to know***.

Off the top of my head, some such questions :

- [Is there any decent speech recognition software for Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256138/decent-speech-recognition-software-for-linux)
- [How to stop feeling guilty about the unfinished work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17988/2740)
- [Comment se nomment les mots de type Xo-Y ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1816/1514)
- [The problem with extrinsic motivation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42481/197593)

Here, the ratio of question to top answer score is ~2. I'm used to questions being upvoted to 10-20, while the answers - either poor workarounds, or variations on "it's not possible / we don't know" - stay under ~5. (Of course, this depends on the site size.)

Typically, askers either leave it unanswered "until a better answer is provided" - meaning forever, or accept whatever scored best but which everyone agrees is not a satisfying answer (hence the voting pattern).

Is this phenomenon well known, and for starters, **how can I see the list of such questions ?** (some answer score >2, sorted by decreasing question score over answer score ratio)

Answer (score 3):

I found this Data.SE query:

- [Bad answers to good questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116726/bad-answers-to-good-questions)

It finds answers of score <-5 to questions of score >50, and orders them by answer score. You can adjust this (click "fork query" to get an editable version of the same query) to find, say, answers of score <2 to questions of score >20, and order by (answer score)/(question score).

Comment: Thanks ! It's the perfect tool, and I should learn to use it. What's missing right now is the ***top* answer** part. As it stands, it selects any question/answer pair, so if I sort by decreasing question/answer score, it's the **worst** answer to any question that will score best (while I want the min score over its answers, maximised over questions).