# Would an increase in the positive motivation to take care of newbies be useful?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges, new-users, code-of-conduct

The new CoC operates mainly with negative motivation, i.e. the unfriendly welcome, particularly to newbies, is forbidden. Violating it results in punishment.

Maybe the system could have a positive motivation side, too?

I intentionally leave open the question of how, exactly; if the answer is yes, we can talk about that. I am thinking of new badges, or maybe even reputation (for edit, answer or comment, so anything that takes care of a newbie).

Answer (score 6):

We already have badges that, while not specifically about new users, are for activities that tend to come up a lot when interacting with new users, like:

- Explainer, Refiner, and Illuminator, for both editing and answering a question
- Custodian, Reviewer, and Steward, which can be earned for First Posts, Reopen, Close, and other review queues
- Editor, Strunk & White, Copy Editor, and Organizer, for edits
- Commentator and Pundit for comments, though I admit that comments aren't necessarily helpful
- Tenacious and Unsung Hero, for helpful answers where the asker can't upvote

I don't think we need to add new-user-flavored badges; rather, helping new users is an easy and mutually beneficial way to earn badges that already exist.

Comment: Ok, but the question was not if we want the currently existing positive motivators (we have them), the question was, do we want more.

Comment: @peterh and my answer is that we don't need more.

Comment: Ok, but so you only state that we don't need. I miss some reasoning, why. I think, if there is this new rule, and it is *only* about negative motivation, maybe some... reward could also appear in exchange.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with *extrinsic* motivation is that, well the moment someone gets that reward, they either want more rewards *or* they lose interest.

As an experienced user, and someone who's seen the rise and fall (or at least the slow decline) of internet communities there's two factors here.

A *stagnant* community community is unhealthy. People leave, they lose interest. In a long running set of communities like this, well, people even die. As someone *interested* in various communities in SE, my intrinsic motivation is having these spaces thrive and grow.

I don't need a COC to go "hey, this new user's post could use a little love." or even better "This post is terrible but the tool he's using is *really cool* and by improving the post with the stuff I've learnt over the time I've been on SE, it can be more useful".

In a sense building a sense of community and shaping that *intrinsic* motivation to improve posts is important. And the way to do that really is to engage folks and have them.

That's to say, it would be, but at a less obvious level.

Comment: Good answer, probably it will be the best. Also I've read Jon Ericsson's [article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42481/259412) about this. However, that post considers only positive motivation (the effect of the reward). Now the new CoC gave exclusively negative motivation (if you don't follow, you will be suspended).