# Yearling badge bug for Sneakers O'Toole?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, yearling-badge, easter-eggs

Lookie at [Sneakers O'Toole's account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10?tab=stats#tab-top) (an easter egg test account btw)

You'll notice that he has the yearling badge, yet the yearling badge states "Active member for a year earning at least 200 reputation". He currently only has a reputation of 101 and he has never gotten any reputation from questions or answers. Though he may be considered active since he was seen a few months ago logged in.

Is this just because the user is so old or is this an actual bug in the Yearling Badge checking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yearling used to require a mere 100 rep, until [I raised a massive amount of heck about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32626/could-account-association-cheapen-the-yearling-badge).  There's a window of four months or so between when Sneakers was around for a year and when Jeff raised the bar.

So, you could say this is by Popular Demand.

[ba dum pshhh](http://www.instantrimshot.com/)

<sup>(Finally, changing my Meta name pays off!)</sup>

Comment: ah, lol. I'm not takin' my sneakers off! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrhNoljPtok