# Many users with 200 rep and over a year on system don't have Yearling badge

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer, yearling-badge

I noticed a few users who had over 200 reputation and had been in the system for over a year but did not have the yearling badge.  It seems like given the criteria, they should have the badge.  They day I hit a year, I got the badge immediately.

To investigate this more, I wrote a query ([available here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1308/users-with-over-200-reputation-and-1-year-on-system-without-yearling-badge)) to see how many users fell into this category.  I compensated for the data delay and looked for users over a year and about a month.

Why are there so many people with over 200 reputation and over a year on the system who do not have the Yearling badge?

Comment: Check out the detailed `yearling` description at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions

Comment: The query is not working properly, for example it brought back [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/304024/alois-cochard) who does have that badge..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard the data provided in that system is at least a month old at most times.  A user could have received enough rep points in the mean time to get the badge.  It is the best we can do with the data available.

Comment: I see, didn't know the data is so old.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you look at the description of the [Yearling badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling) on the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258), it says:

> #### Yearling
>
> - silver; awarded multiple times
> - Have `reputation ≥ (number of years as an active user) × 200`
>
>   - The script that awards this badge only runs on the anniversary of you joining the site
>   - If you do not qualify for Yearling on an anniversary, but do meet it before your next anniversary, the badge **will** be awarded
>
>     - Example: A user who earns 190 rep in his first year will not be awarded Yearling on his first anniversary. If the user earns 40 more rep exactly one month after the first anniversary, the Yearling badge will be awarded the next time the badge script runs. This is because (190 + 40 = 230 rep) > (200 rep / year × 1 1/12<sup>th</sup> years = 217 rep)
>   - The badge used to require only `years × 100` rep; this was [changed after the account association bonus was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32626/could-account-association-cheapen-the-yearling-badge)

Looking at the accounts on your list, they don't appear to have the 200 rep **per year** required for the badge.

Comment: but 1 / 12th = 12

Comment: @Tim - 200 ÷ 12 is ~16.6667.

Comment: So I'm assuming that this is what 'active' means in the description of the badge on the main site.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, but isn't the badge only awarded when the user is logging in?

I mean someone might now register, earn 300 reputation in 6 months then not visit the site for a year - as far as I came to know the badge will be added only when he's visiting again.

Comment: This is a valid part of the answer: there are a lot of people who will get one the next time they access the site—but not until then.

Comment: Thanks @Dori for clarifying. :)