# Why am I getting so many "yearling" badges today?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, reputation-recalc, yearling-badge

Here is a screenshot showing this:

[image: Lots of yearling badges]

Originally I thought it was due to the [rep recalculation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) today, but on most if not all of these sites, I had 200 rep or more both before *and* after the recalculation.

Is everybody getting this effect in their notifications?

Comment: @Marvin, I think you're right.  I hadn't realized that it's possible to earn more than one "yearling" badge on the same site.  If you want to post that as an answer, I would accept it (after giving some time in case a more definitive answer comes in).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The description of the [Yearling badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=5871) is:

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

That means you only get the badge for years in which you earned 200 reputation on the site. So if you'd asked one or more questions and received upvotes on them some previous year, you might have fallen short of getting the 200 reputation under the old system. If under the brand new (or perhaps, [original](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916123307/http://stackoverflow.com/faq)) reputation system you *do* earn 200 reputation for the year, you get the badge for that year. (You can earn the badge even if you [didn't participate on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124734/1438) during the year, by the way.)

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to determine from the badge award page which year you've just earned:

[image: Which badges did I just earn?]

I'm pretty sure one of them is *this year*, but I can't be sure unless [I look in the database](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1148260/maybe-earned-yearling-for-this-year?UserId=5871). But that's odd, I didn't earn 200 reputation *any* of the years on TeX/LaTeX, but I have 4 Yearlings:

```
Year Reputation gain 
---- --------------- 
2011  140             
2012   60              
2013   70              
2014   90              
2015   90              
2016   90              
2017   30              
2018   90              
2019   60
```

In fact, it appears the code doesn't *exactly* do what the description implies:

```
Select [some columns]
  From IntegerRangeCTE years
       Cross Join [some other tables]
 Where DATEADD(Year, years.i, u.CreationDate) < GETUTCDATE()
   And u.Reputation > years.i * 200
Group By [selected columns]
Having COUNT(years.i) > IsNull(b.BadgeCount, 0)
```

In other words, it seems the code effectively divides the user's reputation by 200 (rounded down) and makes sure that they've served at least that many years and awards no more badges than the user has been on the site. (I believe `IntegerRangeCTE` is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869684/1438).) So my reputation on TeX/LaTeX went from 585 (two badges) to 825 (four badges) because of question votes and I suddenly earn two more Yearlings.

I don't know if that's reasonable way to award the badge, but it's not really how I read the badge description. Most likely this is a good enough approximation unless you are changing the reputation payout for questions or something crazy like that. At any rate, I think it *does explain* all the extra Yearling badges.

Comment: *unless you are changing the reputation payout for questions or something crazy like that* .. turns out it are crazy times ;)

Comment: Should Mortarboard badges (rep cap) be awarded, too, when reached now? According to /reputation I reached it two times, but I haven’t gotten any badge.

Comment: @MEE-ReinstateMonica: It should be. But note there is only one Mortarboard per site. Those extra days get you closer to Epic and Legendary, however.

Comment: @JonEricson I am talking about MSE. As you can see in my profile, I have not yet gotten one. According to the /reputation page I have reached the rep cap 2 times, however.

Answer (score 14):

I think that this is indeed due to [today's rep recalculation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/).

You may have had 200 reputation even before the change but since the reputation was changed retroactively you might now have reached the threshold sooner, making you eligible for additional badges.

Answer (score 6):

Presumably, this is because of the increase in value for upvotes on questions all being tallied on one day.  https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1

Either the badge calls for 200 rep DURING THE YEAR, and not a total, or it requires some activity during the year to generate the badge.  The uptick in points activates the activity trigger.