# Yearling badge awarded to the same user in two days

Tags: support, yearling-badge

Today I've earned the "Yearling" badge. When I'm checking the other users who are all received the same badge in the [recent time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling), there I can see a strange behaviour.

For the user [Anil Dash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/149987/anildash), the Yearling badge was awarderd two times in two days. The first one was awarded on **2019-12-19 16:50:12Z** and the second one was awarded on **2019-12-20 10:20:09Z**. When clicking on the both links, it is redirecting to the same user profile.

What is the reason behind that?

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Yearling awarded to same user]

Comment: This is by design; see the badge criteria (the bottom of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/377214) to [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for)).

Comment: I think this Q&A explains a similar situation https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338168/why-am-i-getting-so-many-yearling-badges-today although I do not think yours is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The Yearling badge is awarded for (200 reputation) × (years with an account). So, for instance, if I have a new account, and earn four hundred reputation, it'll be two years until I have two Yearling badges. But if I have an account and it sits for two years, and then one day I earn four hundred rep, then I'll earn two Yearling badges immediately. If I earn less than four hundred rep, I'll get one Yearling badge, because it's two hundred rep per year with an account - no matter when that rep was earned.

I didn't actually check to see if that's what happened here, but given the user in question I think it's safe to assume that it is.

Comment: When I checked the user's [reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/149987/anildash?tab=reputation&sort=post), the reputation was earned in the last two days, and the user was member for more than 9 years in this site.