# Yearling badge awarded multiple times within a year

Tags: support, badges, yearling-badge

Is this a bug?

**[Yearling]**

```
Awarded 9 mins ago    
Awarded May 31 at 19:33    
Awarded May 31 at 10:55  
Awarded May 6 at 19:40
```

[image: Same Network, multiple time yearling in a year]

Comment: Probably for different accounts?

Comment: No same network (SO)

Comment: @NicoMüller Stack Overflow is a site, not a network. Anyway, you probably didn’t receive 200 reputation points in the last three years, but got them now, so the system retroactively awards you a Yearling badge for every 200 reputation points that you got _now_ for every year that you didn’t yet receive this badge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for). tl;dr: You are awarded yearling badges for every years * 200 rep reputation you have.

Comment: Related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338168/why-am-i-getting-so-many-yearling-badges-today

Comment: @MarkKirby Kind of… that was during the time where question upvotes got +10 instead of +5 reputation points.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses, I didn't know it is awarded retrospectively (I thought this reward is meant to be reward a yearly activity).

Comment: Also, see [Yearling badge awarded to the same user in two days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340811/289905); one of the comments points to the bottom of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/289905) of the linked question.