# Why have I received eight yearling badges for the same site today?

Tags: support, badges, per-site-meta, yearling-badge

Note this is not [Why am I getting so many "yearling" badges today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338168/why-am-i-getting-so-many-yearling-badges-today) as these are all in the same site.

I'm currently at 8 badges by my count.

[image: notification drop down with 8 yearling badges awarded]
[image: recent badges awarded on my profile]

These are all for [Information Security Meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com).

Any idea why I'm seeing this? I've earnt it 9 times on the main site, the last of which was Awarded Jul 26 at 22:18. I have visited that meta site today.

Update: I just received my 9th on meta.

Comment: As to why the badges were awarded one at a time after some delays rather than all at the same time: the script that awards the badge can only award it once, so if you suddenly qualify for multiple, you'll earn it one by one each time the badge script runs.

Comment: 9 since 26/07/2012, 15:17:55 - Awarded on [Meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/yearling?userid=11640) in the last 8 hours, and on [Main](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/yearling?userid=11640) once a year (for each 200 reputation earned, when you didn't have ((200*years) reputation) the awarding was delayed).

Answer (score 21):

You didn't have a Security.Meta account until today; [this SEDE query](https://web.archive.org/web/20210924195402/https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.security/query/1468034) doesn't return any results (and it's based on a snapshot from last Sunday). It's far from obvious, but when you create an account on Waffles Stack Exchange, the system doesn't automatically create an account for you on Waffles.Meta; IIRC (but I could be wrong) that only happens when you actually visit the Meta site.

Apparently, the system then creates a 'backdated' account **with the same creation date** as your main site account. That account is over 9 years old, so eligible for quite some Yearling badges, and the system is now catching up.

Comment: That's makes a lot of sense. I had always assumed the meta account was co-creates but I've been wrong before.

Comment: I'm really feeling for waffles now.

Comment: Where can I find this Waffles.SE you speak of? Are stroopwaffels on-topic there?

Comment: @Joachim perhaps [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waffle)?

Answer (score 12):

Your site meta account [is created when you first visit that Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337886/1038015). Since you have 1905 rep on Information Security and you've been active for 9 years you qualify for min(9, 1905 / 200) badges i.e 9.

Your site Meta account does not however have a separate creation date field, the system uses the main account creation date.